# How to fix NullPointerException for array when switching to different method

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm creating a chess game in Java that requires creating a 2D array of objects to make a chessboard. The array displays as having all the objects inside of it upon its creation, but when I call a different method from a different object, the array is suddenly full of null values.

This is in Java including some JavaFX (I don't think anything is being affected by JavaFX, but it's tagged just in case) ran in Eclipse. I've tried printing the array in multiple locations, and it only works inside createBoard() and not setBoard() (or GUI's startGame() method.

```
public class ChessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        Application.launch(GUI.class, args);
        Player player1 = new Player();
        Player player2 = new Player();
        gui.startGame(player1, player2);
    }
}
```

```
public class GUI extends Application {
    Board chessBoard = new Board();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane chessBoardPane = chessBoard.createBoard();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chessBoardPane, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void startGame(Player player1, Player player2) {
        //printing the array here still produces nulls.
        chessBoard.setBoard(player1, player2);
    }

}
```

```
public class Board {
    private BoardSquare[][] boardArray;
    public static int boardSize = 8;
    //private GridPane boardGrid = null;

    public Board() {
        boardArray = new BoardSquare[boardSize][boardSize];  
    }

    public GridPane createBoard() {
        GridPane chessBoard = new GridPane();
        for (int x = 0; x < boardSize; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < boardSize; y++) {
                StackPane square = new StackPane();
                String color;
                if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                    color = "white";
                } else {
                    color = "black";
                }
                square.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + color + ";");
                chessBoard.add(square, y, x);
                boardArray[x][y] = new BoardSquare(x, y, color, square, null);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            chessBoard.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
            chessBoard.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }
        //at this point, printing the x and y values of the array is possible.
        return chessBoard;
    }

    public void setBoard(Player player1, Player player2) {
        Player currentPlayer = player1;
        for (int x = 0; x < boardSize; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < boardSize; y++) {
                //if (boardArray[x][y] != null) {  <-- error occurs if removed
                    if (y == 0) {
                        if (x == 0 || x == 7) {
                            Rook rook = new Rook(currentPlayer);
                            boardArray[x][y].setPiece(rook); //<-- error
                        }
//etc.
```

Printing boardArray's x and y values inside createBoard prints out the coordinates of the expected 8x8 grid. boardArray should still be full of BoardSquare values when moving to setBoard(), but now suddenly all of the values are null and attempting to print the array's x and y values does nothing. I have no idea why the array is suddenly empty.

Comment: Elements of `boardArray` is only set inside `createBoard()` (by line `boardArray[x][y] = new BoardSquare`). But this `createBoard()` is never invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your `main` method:

1. You create your own instance of the `GUI` class which is different from the one that is launched by the `Application.launch` call. `start` is never called for the `GUI` instance you create in `main`.
2. `Application.launch` blocks until the application exits. By the time that happens, it's too late to pass any information to be used in the gui.

The `Application` instance created by `Application.launch` serves as entry point for the application. For this reason you should move this kind of initialisation to the `start` method:

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane chessBoardPane = chessBoard.createBoard();

    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    this.startGame(player1, player2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chessBoardPane, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```